# angular cli: application building fails on server environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I got an angular application using the `angular-cli (v1.0.0-beta.30)`.
It gets deployed on a server where (next to checking out dependency repos and getting all the assets needed) it should get build. This worklow uses gitLab's `pipeline` feature so whenever my app (or the dependency repos) get new versions the newest version should automatically be build.

This does not work atm while I guess the problems sits in the fact that the used angular-cli (which is called within a bash script triggered by the pipeline) is the local one within the node_modules folder of my angular app.

The bash script calls

`./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng build --base-href ./`

and is complaining with the

`You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.`

error.

Is there a way to configure something like an `execution context` the cli should run in, as I guess it tries to build within the `node_modules` folder i call the cli in?

I could not find anything helpfull in the angular-cli documentation.

Installing the cli globally on the server is not an option as there are several angular projects running on different angular-cli versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is kinda off topic. In my scenario the angular project was originally created with `angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.15`. When it was updated to `1.0.0-beta.30` the package moved from `node_modules/angular-cli` to `node_modules/@angular/cli`. Propably due to caching of the gitLab Pipeline it threw the error stated in the question which led to confusion. When running the new angular-cli version in the bash script via

`./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --base-href ./`

it works like a charm.